# Mllib ALS model predict Error

Tags: apache-spark, machine-learning, spark-streaming, apache-spark-mllib

Facing error for model.predict method MatrixFactorizationModel saying while trying to compile in scala.

```
 val usersProducts = ratings.map{ case Rating(user, product, rate) => (user, product,rate) }
 val predictions =   model.predict(usersProducts).map{ case Rating(user, product, rate) => ((user, product), rate)}
```

Error : not enough arguments for method predict: (user: Int, product: Int)Double.

Comment: Can you please incorporate your entire question in one post instead of adding multiple comments? You can edit your question, if you missed any information.

Answer (score 2):

`MatrixFactorizationModel.predict()` takes either an RDD of `(user, product)` pairs or a single user and product pair as two input arguments. Please check the API [docs](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.mllib.recommendation.MatrixFactorizationModel).

In your code, you should change it to:

```
val usersProducts = ratings.map{ case Rating(user, product, rate) => (user, product) }
```